# Write a loop that adds up the weekly salaries of all the players in your dictionary. Print out this total weekly salaries bill

Tags: python

This is the program I have so far and I wonder, how to add up all the weekly salaries and how to find the average:

```
Chelsea_Salaries_2014 = {'Jose Mourinho':[53, 163500, 'Unknown']}
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Eden Hazard']=[22, 185000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Fernando Torres']=[29, 175000, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['John Terry']=[32, 175000, 'June 2015']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Frank Lampard']=[35, 125000, 'June 2014']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ashley Cole']=[32, 120000, 'June 2014']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Petr Cech']=[31, 100000, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Gary Cahill']=[27, 80000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['David Luiz']=[26, 75000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['John Obi Mikel']=[26, 75000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Nemanja Matic']=[25, 75000, 'June 2019']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Marco Van Ginkel']=[20, 30000, 'June 2018']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ramires']=[26, 60000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Oscar']=[21, 67500, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Lucas Piazon']=[19, 15000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ryan Bertrand']=[23, 35000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Marko Marin']=[27, 35000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Cesar Azpilicueta']=[23, 55000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Branislav Ivanovic']=[29, 67500, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Ross Turnbull']=[22, 17000, 'June 2017']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Demba Ba']=[28, 65000, 'June 2016']
Chelsea_Salaries_2014['Oriol Romeu']=[22, 15000, 'June 2015']

Total_Wages_Week = Chelsea_Salaries_2014.count('2')
print(str(Total_Wages_Week))
```

Comment: Did you try to construct the list of salaries with a comprehension list (for instance) and compute the sum (and the mean) via the sum function?

Comment: I have completed the program. Thanks very much to sshashank124 for his solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that as:

```
>>> print sum(i[1] for i in Chelsea_Salaries_2014.values())/len(Chelsea_Salaries_2014)
82295
```

Comment: It says that the sum is an invalid syntax though

Comment: @Calvin_Medcalf, Are you sure. I just ran it and it worked. What problem does it have. And did you copy the code properly?

Comment: print sum(i[1] for i in Chelsea_Salaries_2014.values())/len(Chelsea_Salaries_2014). It wont run the program because it says it is an invalid syntax. Could it be an error in the above code though?

Comment: sshashank's code is ok. You did something wrong, Calvin. Probably you are using python 3 and need print( ... ) instead of bracket-less print ... ?

Comment: Am I supposed to delete the Total_Wages_Week = Chelsea_Salaries_2014.count('2')

Comment: @Calvin_Medcalf, Yes.

Comment: Sorry about that. The example solution you provided me with was missing a ( after the print, meaning that there had to be a ) at the end

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 3.4, there is a `mean` method in the `statistics` module. So you can just do:

```
from statistics import mean
average_salary = mean((i[1] for i in Chelsea_Salaries_2014.values()))
```

The sum can be found using the `sum` function:

```
salary_sum = sum(i[1] for i in Chelsea_Salaries_2014.values())
```

Comment: This does not address the question (does not add up nor compute the avarage) and even if we consider "average" in terms of median - it won't work, since values() are lists of values, where you are interested only in one particular element of the list. So downvote, because this answer does not work.

Comment: @lejlot: please check the edit. I meant to use `mean` not `median`.

Comment: it still won't work. Did you even read the data structure provided by Calvin?

Comment: @lejlot: Is it ok now?

Comment: Now its fine (identical to shashank's in fact).